# document.addEventListener("visibiltyChange") Stops listening after period of time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a live chat app using react.js and am running into an issue when using document.addEventListener("visibiltyChange", () => {}, false).

The purpose is to disconnect the user from a chat when the app is "hidden", the problem is this listener stops working when idle in the background so when reentering the app, visibly is still stuck in the "hidden" state.

PS: this is only happening on android

Comment: You might be able to use the 'focus' event to help: `window.addEventListener('focus', ...)`.

Comment: why would that help?